# Overwrite existing files with Python's "wget"?

Tags: python, wget

I have installed wget on my Python, and I'm downloading files from different URLs with it. So far my code looks like this:

```
import wget
urls = ['https://www.iedb.org/downloader.php?file_name=doc/epitope_full_v3.zip', 
        'https://www.iedb.org/downloader.php?file_name=doc/tcell_full_v3.zip',
        'https://www.iedb.org/downloader.php?file_name=doc/bcell_full_v3.zip', 
        'https://www.iedb.org/downloader.php?file_name=doc/mhc_ligand_full_single_file.zip']
path = '/home/david/data/files/zip_files'

for url in urls:
   wget.download(url, path)
```

I want my code to overwrite the downloaded files if they exist, so that way every time I run the code I get the latest version of that files, instead of keeping the old ones and downloading the new ones with a different name (e.g, if epitope_full_v3.zip already exists, when I execute the code it will download it again, but will keep the old one and rename the new one to epitope_full_v3_1.zip).

I know that wget can take an -O argument in the shell that allows you to do that, but I have not seen that for the python version on the documentation. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although `wget` doesn't mentioned that, you could change it by yourself.Use `os.path.basename()` to get the filename, and check whether it exists.Like this:

```
import wget
import os

urls = ['https://www.iedb.org/downloader.php?file_name=doc/epitope_full_v3.zip',
        'https://www.iedb.org/downloader.php?file_name=doc/tcell_full_v3.zip',
        'https://www.iedb.org/downloader.php?file_name=doc/bcell_full_v3.zip',
        'https://www.iedb.org/downloader.php?file_name=doc/mhc_ligand_full_single_file.zip']

path = '/home/david/data/files/zip_files'

for url in urls:
    filename = path + '/' + os.path.basename(url) # get the full path of the file
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        os.remove(filename) # if exist, remove it directly
    wget.download(url, out=filename) # download it to the specific path.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've eddited a bit the answer because it was not saving the files into the folder I wanted. Thank you for your help, appreciated it a lot! :D

Comment: @DavidMasnouSánchez I forget to change that when I test it on my PC.You could also add `/` in the `path` variable directly.

Comment: It would be nice if `wget` would provide this functionality within the `download()` function - now if the download fails for some reason you end up with neither the old or the new version of the file.